# segfault on write() with ~8MB buffer (OSX, Linux)

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, bsd

I was curious what kind of buffer sizes write() and read() could handle on Linux/OSX/FreeBSD, so I started playing around with dumb programs like the following:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main( void ) {
    size_t s = 8*1024*1024 - 16*1024;
    while( 1 ) {
        s += 1024;
        int f = open( "test.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IXUSR );
        char mem[s];
        size_t written = write( f, &mem[0], s );
        close( f );
        printf( "(%ld) %lu\n", sizeof(size_t), written );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This allowed me to test how close to a seeming "8MB barrier" I could get before segfaulting.  Somewhere around the 8MB mark, my program dies, here's an example output:

```
(8) 8373248
(8) 8374272
(8) 8375296
(8) 8376320
(8) 8377344
(8) 8378368
(8) 8379392
(8) 8380416
(8) 8381440
(8) 8382464
Segmentation fault: 11
```

This is the same on OSX and Linux, however my FreeBSD VM is not only much faster at running this test, it also can go on for quite a ways! I've successfully tested it up to 511MB, which is just a ridiculous amount of data to write in one call.

What is it that makes the write() call segfault, and how can I figure out the maximum amount that I can possibly write() in a single call, without doing something ridiculous like I'm doing right now?

(Note, all three operating systems are 64-bit, OSX 10.7.3, Ubuntu 11.10, FreeBSD 9.0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *fault* isn't within `write()`, it's a stack overflow.  Try this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main( void )
{
    void *mem;
    size_t s = 512*1024*1024 - 16*1024;
    while( 1 )
    {
        s += 1024;
        int f = open( "test.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IXUSR );
        mem = malloc(s);
        size_t written = write( f, mem, s );
        free(mem);
        close( f );
        printf( "(%ld) %lu\n", sizeof(size_t), written );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *sigh* I really should have realized that.  I thought about it, and then promptly forgot to think before compiling.  Thank you!

Comment: @staticfloat I tried to see if I could *prove* it was a stack overflow using `strace` and `gdb` but I couldn't - perhaps someone could suggest how a stack overflow can be definitively determined to be the cause of a fault.

Comment: In case you were wondering, that actually did fix the problem.  :)